# Where does a memoized python function's cache live?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memoization

Below is a simple example of a memoized factorial function.  It works fine, and I understand the basic concept, but one detail confuses me.  Where does the variable `memory` reside?  Why does it persist after `memoize()` finishes executing?  It doesn't seem to be a global variable since I can't do something like `print memory`.  What is going on here?

```
def memoize(f):
    memory = {}
    def memoized(*args):
        if args not in memory:
            memory[args] = f(*args)
        return memory[args]
    return memoized

@memoize
def fact(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n - 1)

print fact(10)
```

Comment: it exists in the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) wrapping `fact`

Comment: When you declare a function inside another one, the inner function can see all variables declared in the outer function. It is called closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memory` dict is stored in a "closure", which is created when a function references local variables from enclosing functions.  The closure wraps these references.

You can see the dict as `fact.__closure__[1].cell_contents`.  (`fact.__closure__[0].cell_contents` is the original undecorated function, which is also referenced by the decorated function in a similar way via the variable `f`.)

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize you could introspect the closure so easily!